# Parse PFQuery - Check if arrays are identical - Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I'm attempting to construct a parse query in xcode that takes an array of objects that was passed to the view controller via a previous segue, creates an array of objectId's from those objects, and queries for an exact match in array objectId values within the key "participants" in the class "MessageThread"

I've been reading through the parse documentation, and the best query I can come up with is containsAllObjectsIn:

Obviously, containsAllObjectsIn will work in some conditions. However, that query only checks that all the objectIds are present in the key "participants". It does not check if the arrays are identical. As such, the query will return objects that, while they do contain all objectIds, may contain extra objectIds.

To counter act this negative effect, I run a check on each returned object to see if the objectIds in the returned object are an identical match to the original array. I've included the view controller code below.

While the code I've currently settled with below seems to be working as intended after testing, I can't help but know there has to be a much more efficient way of checking if the arrays are identical via a PFQuery.

Any ideas or help on how I can make this code better? Thanks.

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class MessageThreadViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var sendNewMessageButton: UIButton!

var participantsList:[PFObject] = []
var participantsListIds:[String] = []
var currentMessageThreadObject:PFObject?
var threadMessages:[PFObject] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    initialViewSetup()
    checkForExistingMessageThread()
}

func initialViewSetup() {
    sendNewMessageButton.isEnabled = false
    for participant in participantsList {
        participantsListIds.append(participant.objectId!)
    }
}

func checkForExistingMessageThread () {
    print("-------------------")
    print(participantsListIds)
    let query = PFQuery(className: "MessageThread")
    query.whereKey("participants", containsAllObjectsIn: participantsList)
    query.includeKey("messages")
    query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (threads, error) in
        if error != nil {
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }
        } else {
            if let threads = threads {
                if threads.isEmpty {
                    print("no thread found. creating thread....")
                    self.createMessageThread()
                } else {
                    print("existing thread match(es) found")
                    var activeThreadFound = false
                    for thread in threads {
                        let returnedThreadParticipants = thread["participants"] as! [PFObject]
                        var returnedThreadParticipantsIds:[String] = []
                        for participant in returnedThreadParticipants {
                            returnedThreadParticipantsIds.append(participant.objectId!)
                        }
                        if returnedThreadParticipantsIds.containsSameElements(as: self.participantsListIds) {
                            activeThreadFound = true
                            print("thread identical match found")
                            self.currentMessageThreadObject = thread
                            self.sendNewMessageButton.isEnabled = true
                            if let queriedThreadMessages = thread["messages"] {
                                let queriedThreadMessagesAsObjects = queriedThreadMessages as! [PFObject]
                                self.threadMessages = queriedThreadMessagesAsObjects
                                self.messagesTableView.reloadData()
                                self.sendNewMessageButton.isEnabled = true
                            }
                            break
                        } else {

                            print("non-identical thread found")
                        }
                    }
                    if activeThreadFound == false {
                        print("matches were found, but no identical thread. Creating thread....")
                        self.createMessageThread()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
}

func createMessageThread() {
    let newMessageThread = PFObject(className:"MessageThread")
    newMessageThread["participants"] = participantsList
    newMessageThread.saveInBackground(block: { (success, error) in
        if error != nil {
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }
        } else {
            self.checkForExistingMessageThread()
        }
    })

}

}

extension Array where Element: Comparable {
func containsSameElements(as other: [Element]) -> Bool {
    return self.count == other.count && self.sorted() == other.sorted()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
query.whereKey("participants", equalTo: [
    "$eq" : participantsList
])
```

Comment: Hey Davi, thanks for the suggestion. I gave your query a go, and received the following error: "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot do a comparison query for type: _TtGCs26_SwiftDeferredNSDictionarySSGSaCSo6PFUser__'"

Comment: Looks like I need to do a comparison against an array of user id's? Would it matter if the two comparing array elements are not arranged in the same order?

Comment: Hmmm... they only problem though is that "participants" is a array of pointers to user objects.

Comment: I tested in the API and it worked fine, but it doesn't pass in the SDK validation. I think you will be able to do it from cloud code. But first I will send another suggestion in a separate response. If it doesn't work either, I can figure out how to do it from cloud code.

Answer (score 0):

My other suggestion is try to combine containedIn and containsAllObjectsInArray in the same query. Please, try something like this:

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "MessageThread")
query.whereKey("participants", containsAllObjectsInArray: participantsList)
query.whereKey("participants", containedIn: participantsList)
```

Comment: Just gave this code a go, and it seems that this query is still able to match multiple "MessageThread" 's. This unfortunately is the same behavior as the initial query it seems. Bummer.